# Не изменяется глобальная переменная при использовании Pool (python)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

В массив `count` не добавляется переменная `x`, понятия не имею что сделать. При  использовании Process тоже не добавлялось (Потоки не использовал ввиду существования GIL)

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
count = []
def check(c):
    ans = 0
    for ch in str(c):
        ans += int(ch)
    return ans % 2
def dsa(x):
    count = 0
    for c in range(0,(len(x))):
        if x[c] != 0:
            count+=1
    return count
def thread(star,end):
    global count
    x = dsa([check(x) for x in range(star, end+1)])
    print(x)
    count.append(x)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = 1
    B = 10000
    time1 = time.time()
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    start = time.time()
    r1 = pool.apply_async(thread, (A, B//2))
    r2 = pool.apply_async(thread, (B//2+1, B))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(sum(count))
    print(time.time()-time1))
```

Comment: У каждого процесса своя переменная `count`. Это принципиальное отличие процессов от потоков.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, а как я могу обменивать данные между процессами?

Comment: Щас сходу уже не вспомню. Погуглите чё-то, типа "python share variable process".

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Процессы в питон не имеют общей памяти. Для обмена данными лучше пользоваться очередями.

Если надо раздать массив без очередей

```
from multiprocessing import Array
count = Array('i', [])
..
count.append(x)
```

'i' - указывает тип содержимого массива.

В вашем случае map лучше:

```
def thread(star,end):
    global count
    x = dsa([check(x) for x in range(star, end+1)])
    print(x)
    return x

count = pool.map(thread, [(A, B//2),(B//2+1, B)])
```